# How to decrypt .gpg file using terminal of mac

Tags: encryption, terminal, gnupg

Here I've a gpg file and I'm using my mac terminal where I'm using the command

```
gpg -d /path/to/file/file.zip.gpg -o /path/to/file/abc.zip
```

to convert the .gpg file. It is shoing me error

**usage: gpg [options] --decrypt [filename]**

I'm not able to figure it out. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gpg --decrypt -o '/Path/to/store/decrypted/GPG/file/abc.zip' '/Path/of/GPG/file/file.zip.gpg'
```

This is the actual command which can solve the issue. Here we have to mention everything before hand the provide locations in the single quotes. This command will go to the GPG file and then decrypt it and move the decrypted version to specified location.

Comment: Note that with `-o` the path needs to exist but the zip-file-name does not

Comment: when I tried this command I needed to mention file name in order to get exact zip file from bunch of files. @Blundell

Answer (score 1):

The --decrypt goes to the end of the command as showed in the output.

This command might do the trick :

```
gpg -o /path/to/file/abc.zip -d /path/to/file/file.zip.gpg
```

Comment: I've used your command where I've mentioned the proper path with file for -o and not mentioned the file name for -o.

it is giving me error 

**gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
usage: gpg [options] [filename]**